# Print the dictionary value and key(index) in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code which inputs a line from user, splits it and feed it up to majestic dictionary named counts. All is well until we ask her majesty for some data. I want the data in the format such that the word is printed first and number of times it repeats printed next to it. Below is the code I managed to write.

```
counts = dict()
print('Enter a line of text:')
line = input('')

words = line.split()

print('Words:', words)

print('Counting:')
for word in words:
    counts[word]  = counts.get(word,0) + 1
for wording in counts:
    print('trying',counts[wording], '' )
```

When it executes its output is unforgivable.

```
Words: ['You', 'will', 'always', 'only', 'get', 'an', 'indent', 'error', 'if', 'there', 'is', 'actually', 'an', 'indent', 'error.', 'Double', 'check', 'that', 'your', 'final', 'line', 'is', 'indented', 'the', 'same', 'was', 'as', 'the', 'other', 'lines', '--', 'either', 'with', 'spaces', 'or', 'with', 'tabs.', 'Most', 'likely,', 'some', 'of', 'the', 'lines', 'had', 'spaces', '(or', 'tabs)', 'and', 'the', 'other', 'line', 'had', 'tabs', '(or', 'spaces).']
Counting:
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 2 
trying 2 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 2 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 1 
trying 2
```

It just prints trying and number of times it is repeated and without the word(I think it is called index in dictionary, correct me if I am wrong)

```
Thankyou
```

Please help me and when replying to this question please keep in mind I am a newbie, both to python and stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code do you attempt to print the word.  How did you expect it to appear in the output?  If you want the word, put it in the list of things to print:

```
print(wording, counts[wording])
```

For more education, look up the package `collections`, and use the `Counter` construct.

```
counts = Counter(words)
```

will do all of your word counts for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `counts.items()` to iterate over the key and value of `counts` as follows:

```py
counts = dict()
print('Enter a line of text:')
line = input('')

words = line.split()

print('Words:', words)

print('Counting:')
for word in words:
    counts[word]  = counts.get(word,0) + 1
for word, count in counts.items(): # notice this!
    print(f'trying {word} {count}')
```

Also notice that you can use an f-string when printing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confuzled as to why you print `trying`.
Try this instead.

```
counts = dict()
print('Enter a line of text:')
line = input('')

words = line.split()

print('Words:', words)

print('Counting:')
for word in words:
    counts[word]  = counts.get(word,0) + 1
for wording in counts:
    print(wording,counts[wording], '' )
```

Comment: trying was just as a checkpoint that code managed to survive till this point.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have iterates over the dictionary keys and prints only the count in the dictionary. You would want to do something like this:

```
for word, count in counts.items():
    print('trying', word, count)
```

You might also want to use

```
from collections defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
```

So while adding to the dictionary, the code would be as simple as

```
counts[word] += 1
```